# Black Screen error in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am getting Black Screen error in `Google Chrome`.
 I tried reinstalling it, deleted all data then also getting same error. Getting this error for all pages like settings, history etc. Please help me to solve this.
[image: Chrome Error]

Answer (score 0):

This hit me for the first time yesterday.  Initially it was completely black (even the tabs) except for the very top of the Title bar.

Searching the web found a few things to try, but the only place I found the fix that worked for me was on youtube (and it was rather hard to follow while trying to get to the same place)... *ergo*, I thought I'd post what worked for me here so others might find it in text form to prevent having to follow a video and navigate at the same time.

You didn't provide much info about your system, so here's mine:
Dell Precision M5510, Win10 Pro (x64) with both Intel 530 integrated and NVIDIA Quadro M1000M (2GB GDDR5).

**Completely black screen on Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit)**

Adding the --disable-gpu" switch helped very little (got its tabs back, but Address and Bookmarks bars, and everything below that was still black).

Nor did right-clicking the shortcut and choosing to use integrated graphics instead of the NVIDIA card help any.

Deleting all files in

**%TEMP%..\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage**

fixed it for me. Copy+Paste that line into File Explorer (*nee* Windows Explorer) then hit **Enter** and it should take you to the proper folder.

I actually just moved them to c:\temp\save first, in case it didn't help... but as soon as I opened Chrome after doing that it was back to normal.

Hope that helps!